# open js popup by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have index html page in my site, its the main page.
in the index html i have a button and by clicking it i want to open a popup form, i have the js file and css file of this popup included in the index html.

i just cant open this animated popup by clicking the input type button..
can anyone help me?

```
the clouds js:

        $(function ()
{
    // Register Smart skin.
    $.speedoPopup.registerSmartSkin('clouds', function (overlay, container)
    {
        // We don't want to brake anything if there is no overlay.
        if (!overlay)
        {
            return ;
        }

        if ($.speedoPopup.browser_ie && $.speedoPopup.browser_ie< 9)
        {
            return;
        }

        var clouds = '<div class="cloud x1"></div><div class="cloud x2"></div><div class="cloud x3"></div><div class="cloud x4"></div><div class="cloud x5"></div>';

        overlay.append(clouds);
    });
});
```

index html: below the head tag

```
<link type='text/css' href='clouds/clouds.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='clouds/clouds.js'></script>
```

and the button:

```
<div>
<input type='button' name='clouds' value='Clouds'/>
</div>
```

Comment: have you included jQuery in the `<head>` of your file? Also, try setting your problem up in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes.. this is what i wrote.. clouds.js included look up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke the dialog on click

Lets give you button an id

```
<div>
<input id="btnDialog" type='button' name='clouds' value='Clouds'/>
</div>
```

Now create a div that you want to show in dialog

```
<div  id="divContentToPopup">
   ...content here...
</div>
```

now you have to hook a click event on it

```
$('#btnDialog').click(function ()
{
    $(this).speedoPopup(
    {
        width:550,
        height:265,
        useFrame: TRUE,
        href: '#divContentToPopup'
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok i understand. And the click event code should be in my js file or as a script  in the html page?

Comment: It is up to you where you want to place click handler... keep it in page in a script tag for now